# C++ Generator for permutations with a twist (decreasing each position)

Tags: c++, c++11, combinations, permutation, c++03

I'm no mathematician, so I don't know if there is terminology for this (I could not find it).

What I'm looking for is C++ code to generate all permutations, with repetition, but with a twist: the first position can have `n-1` as the highest value, the second can have `n-2` as the highest value and so on `n-(n...0)`. E.g. given `n=3` with repetition allowed this should result into:

```
[0,0,0]   ✓
[0,0,1] ✗
[0,0,2] ✗
[0,1,0]   ✓
[0,1,1] ✗
[0,1,2] ✗
[0,2,0] ✗
[0,2,1] ✗
[0,2,2] ✗
[1,0,0]   ✓
[1,0,1] ✗
[1,0,2] ✗
[1,1,0]   ✓
[1,1,1] ✗
[1,1,2] ✗
[1,2,0] ✗
[1,2,1] ✗
[1,2,2] ✗
[2,0,0]   ✓
[2,0,1] ✗
[2,0,2] ✗
[2,1,0]   ✓
[2,1,1] ✗
[2,1,2] ✗
[2,2,0] ✗
[2,2,1] ✗
[2,2,2] ✗
```

So it's like a N-length list of permutations of N with repetition `✗` and `✓` except plus the per position limitation `✓`. Is there an existing name or description for this kind of sequence?

I can make something like a recursive pattern, but I would like a generator. Solely for speed purposes. Is it likely this will be faster than a function? How would you approach this?

Comment: My approach would definitely involve writing some C++ code. I suggest you try it as well. When you have done that, show us your code and a specific question/problem you have with it. See also [ask].

Comment: If you are asking about what algorithm to use, this looks like incrementing numbers digit-by-digit, except it overflows and carries into the next digit when it hits the constraint.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with permutations. As for speed, generating values like this is pretty much instant in C++. I suspect the bottleneck will be writing the values to memory as they are being generated.

Comment: @dratenik: I get your position. Of course I could write code. But that is not specifically my question. My question is more 1) I think I want a generator method for speed purposes, does that make any sense? 2) Is there any terminology I have not yet found I can use to further my approach. I'm not asking you to write any code.

Comment: @MSalters: It kinda is a subset of permutations so I guessed it would be...

Comment: Your example claims that `[2,2,0]` is a valid sequence, but it doesn't appear to satisfy your requirements. Shouldn't the middle position be limited to 0 or 1?

Comment: This has nothing to do with permutations. It's increment with carry (the pencil-and-paper addition you learned in elementary school) in a mixed-base number system. Start with all zeros. Increment the lowest-order digit; if that exceeds the maximum allowable value for that position, reset it to zero and increment the next position (this is the carry); if that in turn exceeds the maximum allowable value, reset it to zero and increment the next position, and so on. Proceed in this manner until the highest-order digit is incremented past its max value.

Answer (score 0):

We can observe the following:

- The values in the columns are limited to the column number
- With a index looking from right to left
- Limiting can be done by modulo division
- If we have a falling edge, a transition from the maximum value of this column to 0, then we need to do something with the next column. We use a carry-value for that
- Special handling for the rightmost column. It is always 0 and has therefore always a falling edge. Carry will always be set.

The difficulty is to play with the indices that run from right to left. These indirections make the code a little bit hard to read.

And, of course as always. There are many different possible solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

constexpr size_t MaxFieldWith = 9;

bool nextSpecialPermutation(std::vector<unsigned int>& v) {
    unsigned int carry{};
    const size_t vectorSize = v.size();

    // Iterate over all columns from right to left
    for (size_t i = vectorSize; i > 0; --i) {

        // Corrected index
        size_t index = i - 1;

        // Limiting value for column
        const unsigned int modValue = (vectorSize - i + 1);

        // And the next value for this column, limited
        const unsigned int nextValue = (v[index] + carry) % modValue;

        // Special handling for right most column
        if (i == vectorSize) {
            // In rightmost  column value is always 0 and carry always 1
            carry = 1;
        }
        else {
            // So, now we are not in a rightmost column
            // Detect a falling edge, and if found, set the carry for the next column
            if ((v[index] == (modValue-1)) && nextValue == 0)
                carry = 1;
            else
                carry = 0;
        }
        // Set the resulting value for this column
        v[index] = nextValue;

    }
    // If all is 0 then we are done
    return not std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto& i) { return i == 0; });
}

int main() {
    // Inform user what to do
    std::cout << "Enter number of columns. Give number >= 2 and <= " << MaxFieldWith << ": ";

    // Get value from user and check, if it is valid
    if (size_t numberOfColumns{}; (std::cin >> numberOfColumns) && (numberOfColumns >= 2) && (numberOfColumns <= MaxFieldWith)) {

        // Create a vector as specified by the user
        std::vector<unsigned int> v(numberOfColumns, 0);

        // Get all special permutations
        bool doLoop{ true };
        while (doLoop) {

            // Debug output
            std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, " "));
            std::cout << '\n';

            // Get next special permutation
            doLoop = nextSpecialPermutation(v);
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError. Invalid input!\n";
    return 0;
}
```